# Pagination with html, and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a webpage and need a bit of help. I'm trying to get the pagination to work and I can't seem to get it working any help?

Thanks to anyone helping I've been stuck on this for weeks.

```css
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    width: 25%;
    left: 250px;
}

.pagination a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

.pagination a.active {
    background-color: skyblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
  <a href="#1" class="active">1</a>
  <a href="page2">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">6</a>
  <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you define 'not working'? What is it that you would like to achieve that you have not currently achieved? You cannot make a pagination system with purely HTML and CSS, and you haven't included any JavaScript in your question. have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination, as the name suggests, serves to change pages (results). So you must have a system serving subsequent pages.

It will be the easest to create next files like `page1.html`,`page2.html`... and link for it in all pages.

You can also send all results immediately and hide them appropriately using methods similar to those used by `pure css menu` (input + label + ~ (css))

**But this is extremely stupid. (Though possible)**

You must use some programming language for this. JavaScript on the browser side or / and something on the server side, e.g.: PHP, NodeJS, .Net, c#, Python, Perl, Ruby, Java... Even assembler